# How do I set the margins in a KOMA-Script class?

Tags: margins, koma-script

I am writing my resume (using the `currvita` package) within a `scrartcl` document class from KOMA-Script. How do I set the margins? I think the text width is a bit too narrow for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what `currvita` has to do with this question. The KOMA-script class is what would be setting the margin. See chapter two of the KOMA-script guide for how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may also want to redefine the areaset  `\areaset[5mm]{412pt}{657pt}` but it may destroy the original behavior of the class.

Answer (score 22):

As TH. has hinted, chapter 2 of the KOMA-script documentation deals with page layouts. The most important class option is `DIV` (the division factor for box construction), with a default value of 10 (appropriate for a font size of 11pt). If the text width is "a bit too narrow" for you, try

```
\documentclass[DIV=12]{scrartcl}
```